# Is this process of Brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, wienerprocess

**Background Information:**

The process $W = (W_t:t\geq 0)$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-Brownian motion if and only if

i) $W_t$ is continuous, and $W_0 = 0$

ii) the value of $W_t$ is distributed, under $\mathbb{P}$, as a normal random variable $N(0,t)$,

iii) the increment $W_{s+t} - W_{s}$ is distributed as a normal $N(0,t)$, under $\mathbb{P}$, and is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$, the history of what the process did up to time $s$.

**Question:**

If $W_t$ and $\tilde{W}_t$ are two independent Brownian motions and $\rho$ is a constant between $-1$ and $1$, then the process $X_t = \rho W_t - \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tilde{W}_t$ is continuous and has marginal distributions $N(0,t)$. Is this $X$ a Brownian motion?

We have the first two conditions met. Now we must check if $X_{s+t} - X_s~N(0,t)$, and if $X_{s+t} - X_s$ is independent of $X_s$. One problem I having here is what is $X_{s+t}$, would it be $X_{s+t}= \rho W_{s+t} + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tilde{W}_{s+t}$, and if so is $W_{s+t}$ and $\tilde{W}_{s+t}$ two independent Brownian motions?

Updated- We have 
\begin{align*}
X_{s+t} - X_{s} &= \rho W_{s+t} + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tilde{W}_{s+t} - \rho W_s + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tilde{W}_s\\
&= \rho(W_{s+t} - W_s) - \sqrt{1-\rho^2}(\tilde{W}_{s+t} - \tilde{W}_s)\\
&\sim N(0,t)
\end{align*}
Since $W_{s+t} - W{s}\sim N(0,t)$ and $\tilde{W}_{s+t}-\tilde{W}_s\sim N(0,t)$. Now we need to check if $X_{s+t} - X{s}$ is independent of $X_{s}$. To do so we can check if the expectation of the product is equal to the product of the expectations.

We can show 
$$E\left[(X_{s+t}-X_{s})X_{s}\right]=E[X_{s+t}X_s]-E[X_s^2]=\text{Cov}(X_{t+s},X_s)-\text{Var}(X_s)=s-s=0$$
Hence $X$ is a Brownian motion.

Comment: Those are not difficult questions. I prefer to leave this for you to try.

Comment: Yes, its just my first exposure to these types of questions so I am a bit slow at getting it

Comment: @Gordon is $X_{s+t} = \rho W_{s+t} + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tilde{W}_{s+t}$? And is $W_{s+t}$ and $\tilde{W}_{s+t}$ two independent Brownian motions?

Comment: Yes. $X_{s+t} = \rho W_{s+t} +\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tilde{W}_{s+t}$.  Moreover, $W_{s+t}$ and $\tilde{W}_{s+t}$ are two independent random variables.

Comment: @Gordon made an attempt, could you let me know if I am on the right track?

Comment: I don't really understand what I did that was wrong

Comment: @wolfy Note $X_{t+s}= \rho W_{s+t} - \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tilde{W}_{s+t} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Lévy’s theorem**: Let $X_t$ be a martingale with $X_0=0$. Then the
>   following are equivalent.
>
> 1. $X_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.
> 2. $X_t$ has continuous sample paths and $X_t^2-t$ is a martingale.
> 3. $X_t$ has quadratic variation $[X]_t=t$.

---

> **Proposition:** If $W^{(1)}_t$ and $W^{(2)}_t$ be two independent standard Brownian motions then $W_t:=\rho W^{(1)}_t-\sqrt{1-\rho^2} W^{(2)}_t$  is a Brownian motion.

**Proof**

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P},\{\mathcal{F_t}\})$ be a probability space . Clearly, $W_t$ has continuous sample paths and $W_0=0$. Note

$$\mathbb{E}[W_t|\mathcal{F_s}]=\rho\,\mathbb{E}[W^{(1)}_t|\mathcal{F_s}]-\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\,\mathbb{E}[W^{(2)}_t|\mathcal{F_s}]=\rho W^{(1)}_s-\sqrt{1-\rho^2} W^{(2)}_s=W_s$$
 So $W_t$ is a martingale. Now we should show $W_t^2-t$ is a martingale.By application of Ito's lemma, we have 
$$dW_t^2=2W_tdW_t+d[W_t,W_t]$$
$$dW_t^2=2W_tdW_t+\rho^2 d[W_t^{(1)},W_t^{(1)}]+(1-\rho^2) d[W_t^{(2)},W_t^{(2)}]-2\rho\sqrt{1-\rho^2}d[W_t^{(1)},W^{(2)}_t]$$

Since $W^{(1)}_t$ and $W^{(2)}_t$ are two independent Brownian motions, thus $d[W_t^{(1)},W^{(2)}_t]=0$ , hence
$$dW_t^2=2W_tdW_t+dt$$
consequently
$$d(W_t^2-t)=2W_tdW_t+dt-dt=2W_tdW_t$$
so to speak
$$d(W_t^2-t)=2W_tdW_t$$
Therefore $W_t^2-t$, is a martingale (because it's SDE has a null drift )  and $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.

---

**Another way**

$W_t^{(1)},W_t^{(2)}\stackrel{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}\sim \mathcal N(0,t)$, so $$\rho W_t^{(1)}\sim\mathcal N\left(0,\rho^2 t\right)$$
 and
 $$\sqrt{1-\rho^2}W_t^{(2)}\sim\mathcal N\left(0,(1-\rho^2)t \right)$$ 
thus
$$W_t \sim \mathcal N\left(0, t \right). $$
Therefore $\{W_t:t\in\mathbb R_+\}$ is a Gaussian process, and from independence of $W_t^{(1)}$ and $W_t^{(2)}$ we have $$\mathbb E\left[W_t^{(1)}W_t^{(2)}\right] =\mathbb E\left[W_t^{(1)}\right]\mathbb E\left[W_t^{(2)}\right]=0.$$ Let $0<s<t$ we have
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(W_s,W_t) &= \mathbb E[W_sW_t] - \mathbb E[W_s]\mathbb E[W_t]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[\left(\rho W_s^{(1)}-\sqrt{1-\rho^2}W_s^{(2)}\right)\left(\rho W_t^{(1)}-\sqrt{1-\rho^2}W_t^{(2)}\right)\right] - 0\\
&= \rho^2\mathbb E\left[W_s^{(1)}W_t^{(1)} \right]+(1-\rho^2) \mathbb E\left[W_s^{(2)}W_t^{(2)} \right] - 2\rho\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\mathbb E\left[W_s^{(1)}W_t^{(2)} \right]\\
&= \rho^2 s + \left(1-\rho^2\right)s - \rho\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\times 0\\
&= s.
\end{align} 
on the other hand
$$\mathbb{E}[(W_t-W_s)W_s]=\mathbb{E}[W_t\,W_s]-\mathbb{E}[W_s^2]=\text{Cov}(W_t,W_s)-\text{Var}(W_s)=s-s=0$$

Comment: +1. This is good. But, it appears that @Wolfy is still at a very early stage to understand this. Can you please also give him the rudimentary approach to show that $(W_t: t\ge 0)$ is a Brownian motion by definition?

Comment: So thanks. Yes I will show it as soon as possible.

Comment: I don't see where I went wrong in my solution seems that I was able to show that $X_{s+t} - X_{s}\sim N(0,t)$ and $X_{s+t} - X_{s}$ is independent of $X_s$

Comment: I don't understand your solution really, but thank you

Comment: @Wolfy Please Note $X_t = \rho W_t - \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tilde{W}_t$ thus $X_{s+t}= \rho W_{s+t} - \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tilde{W}_{s+t}$

Comment: I know that, I think I showed that in my solution?

Comment: What is wrong with my solution

Comment: \begin{align*}
X_{s+t} - X_{s} &= \rho W_{s+t} - \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tilde{W}_{s+t} - \rho W_s + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\tilde{W}_s\\
&= \rho(W_{s+t} - W_s) - \sqrt{1-\rho^2}(\tilde{W}_{s+t} - \tilde{W}_s)\\
&\sim N(0,t)
\end{align*}

Comment: So I need to fix that part, other than that it is correct, yes?

Comment: Yes correct these typos

Comment: ok thanks I corrected it, I think everything is fine now

Comment: @Wolfy:  In addition, we need to show the independence of $X_{s+t}-X_s$ and $\mathcal{F}_s$, not just $X_{s+t}-X_s$ and $X_s$.

Comment: @Gordon yes $\mathcal{F_s}$ is a natural filtration